# How to retain the time dimension after applying for loop to netcdf timeseries data in python?

Tags: python, time, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file containing total cumulative rainfall data at a **6hourly** time step: i.e. for a given time precipitation value is the **total accumulated rainfall from the starting time of the data**. So I need to compute the **single time-step** rainfall by subtracting the rainfall from the previous time-step. For example, since the available data is at 6h timestep starting from 2023-06-01 06:00 (suppose) upto 2023-06-02 00:00 then  ***past 6-hour rainfall at 2023-06-01 12:00 would be (rainfall at 2023-06-01 12:00 - rainfall at 2023-06-01 06:00 similarly for rainfall at 2023-06-02 00:00  it should be rainfall at 2023-06-02 00:00 - rainfall at 2023-06-01 18:00***

So far I have wrote a code in python like this:

```
import os
import glob
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join("path_to sample data","*6h.nc"))


for file in file_list:
    file=file_list[1]
    aa = xr.open_dataset(file)
    aa = aa.rename_vars({'prate_ave': 'prate'})
    
    new = []
    for j in range(aa.prate.shape[0]):
        if j == 0:
            new.append(aa.prate[0,:,:])
        else:
            new.append(((aa.prate[j,:,:]*j)-(aa.prate[j-1,:,:]*(j-1))))
    acu_precip = xr.concat(new, dim='time')
```

It shows the error:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-f857f1e2148b> in <module>
     14         else:
     15             new.append(((aa.prate[j,:,:]*j)-(aa.prate[j-1,:,:]*(j-1))))
---> 16             acu_precip = xr.concat(new,dim='time')
     17             #new.append(aa.time[j])
     18             #new.expand_dims(time=aa.time[j])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py in concat(objs, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    234 
    235     if isinstance(first_obj, DataArray):
--> 236         return _dataarray_concat(
    237             objs,
    238             dim=dim,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py in _dataarray_concat(arrays, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    660         datasets.append(arr._to_temp_dataset())
    661 
--> 662     ds = _dataset_concat(
    663         datasets,
    664         dim,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py in _dataset_concat(datasets, dim, data_vars, coords, compat, positions, fill_value, join, combine_attrs)
    565             # Try concatenate the indexes, concatenate the variables when no index
    566             # is found on all datasets.
--> 567             indexes: list[Index] = list(get_indexes(name))
    568             if indexes:
    569                 if len(indexes) < len(datasets):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/concat.py in get_indexes(name)
    549                 yield ds._indexes[name]
    550             elif name == dim:
--> 551                 var = ds._variables[name]
    552                 if not var.dims:
    553                     data = var.set_dims(dim).values

**KeyError: 'time'**
```

**I found that whenever I applied the mathematical operation and assigned it to a list
in case of first case**

```
if j == 0:
            new.append(aa.prate[0,:,:])
```

**It retains the time dimension. whereas for another case**

```
else:
            new.append(((aa.prate[j,:,:]*j)-(aa.prate[j-1,:,:]*(j-1))))
```

**It does not retain the time dimension which is why I think it is throwing the issue of KeyErro: 'time'.** Therefore wanted to ask for help in the group to correct my code or any other better option to do this type of operation in time-series data in NetCDF files.
#link to sample data:
[https://mega.nz/file/1JUECRyK#E1BWhCk-Fj7061KUSISM-tSzrvShAs6xa-aMCMGE88w][1]

I have tried my best to make the question clear, and hoping for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier by using xarray's `.diff(dim=...)` function:

```
# generate data similar to yours
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


np.random.seed(42)
time = pd.date_range("2023-06-06", "2023-06-10", freq="6h")
nt = len(time)
rain_data = np.concatenate(
    [[0], np.cumsum(np.abs(np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=nt - 1)))]
)
rain_accumulated = xr.DataArray(rain_data, coords={"time": time})
print(rain_accumulated)
```

gives

```
<xarray.DataArray (time: 17)>
array([ 0,  2,  5,  5,  7,  9, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 26, 26])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2023-06-06 2023-06-06T06:00:00 ... 2023-06-10
```

then:

```
# differentiate by time
rain_6hrly = rain_accumulated.diff(dim="time")

# and plot
plt.plot(rain_accumulated.time, rain_accumulated)
plt.bar(rain_6hrly.time, rain_6hrly, width=0.1)
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jspaeth for your answer. Sorry that I forgot to mention one detail earlier as the cumulative value in my dataset is like `sum(0:i)/i   *where i = n-count from start.`  Since the cumulative sum is divided by the n-count from the start, each rainfall value should be multiplied by its n-count from the start before computing the diff. How can I do so? I am very new to Python so stuck on these (maybe) very simple issues.

Comment: `ncount_from_start = xr.ones_like(rain_accumulated) * np.arange(nt)` and then `rain_6hrly = (rain_accumulated * ncount_from_start).diff(dim="time")` Would that do the job?